# Using R function names alongside logic operators

Tags: r

In R, I have a function which takes the name of another function as a parameter. I've constructed an if-statement within the parent function to check if the input function name is the same as the name of an already existing function of the name strategy_function.

```
function_parent <- function(function_name){
    if(function_name == strategy_function){...}
}
```

However, R does not appreciate this notation.  Is using the name of a function in this way possible, and even if it is, is there a better way?  This seems slightly sloppy.

Comment: use quotes around `strategy_function` as in `"strategy_function"`

Comment: Indeed, @TylerRinker, I was just about to ask if `function_name` is a character, the unquoted name of a function or a symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `deparse(substitute(strategy_function))` in the comparison did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Try quotes around `strategy_function`:

```
function_parent <- function(function_name){
    if(function_name == "strategy_function"){...}
}
```

Comment: This returns an error `comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types`